# P*ss one's pants (out of/from/with) fear / laughter

Tags: prepositions, offensive-language

I wonder what preposition do you normally use after the informal idiom "piss one's pants" to join it with the words like "laughter" or "fear" etc.?

**Example 1:**

> — He was really a chicken! I never forget once that the air raid began. Believe it or not he pissed his pants............fear.

a. with 
b. from 
c. out of

**Example 2:**

> - She is hilarious; yesterday she had us pissing our pants ........ laughter.

a. with 
b. from 
c. out of

I wonder what choice is correct here?
If non of them works, please let me know what do you normally use instead?

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of your examples except "out of laughter":

- with fear / from fear / out of fear / in fear
- with laughter / from laughter

Note that "piss" is vulgar.  "Wet" would be a suitable informal word.  These expressions are normally used figuratively.  You can also use "shit" (even more vulgar) or "soil" (informal).

If you use the expressions literally, "wet" and "soil" would be considered polite rather than informal.  For a baby you'd normally say "the baby needs changing" (which means the baby's *nappies* need changing.) ["nappy" (BrE), "diaper" AmE]

Comment: At least in AmE, the expression _peed his pants_ is another less vulgar way to say it.